# Elevated CMD / PowerShell from existing console of CMD / Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, administrator, elevation

I want know to if there is a command to launch CMD prompt or powershell in elevated privileges from an existing CMD / powershell console. Something along the lines of 'sudo' in *NIX where you don't have to close the console and launch it again.

I have often found myself in situations where in the windows UI I navigate to a folder and want to run CMD/powershell with elevated privileges from over there. Typing CMD in the address bar or Holding Shift + Right Click and choosing 'Open Powershell Here' invokes them in a normal mode and not elevated.

Comment: Just to say, the file menu should have an option to launch PS as admin or without in the current directory. You might also find this video useful https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-176-CMD-and-PowerShell-Context-Menus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell: This example starts PowerShell by using the Run as administrator option.

```
Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath "powershell"
```

Replace powershell with the program you want to run elevated.

Comment: thanks, would you be knowing a similar way for CMD prompt assuming I have the CMD prompt opened?

Answer (score 0):

For Powershell, after you navigate to the specified folder, you can click "File" > select "Open Powershell as administrator". Or just hold Alt and type F>S>A.
[image]

For CMD, you can first open CMD as administrator, and type cd . Copy your specified folder path to replace .
[image]

Or you can typr runas /user: Administrator and enter the password.
[image]

Comment: thanks.got the powershell trick both via File menu and via command..but inside the cmd prompt console - if i run **_runas /user: Administrator_ **
it is asking me for password which I have not set. bypassing it with enter also does not work.